# does Altera stratix III or Stratix II devices support partial reconfiguraion

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga

I need to inquire this question that stratix II or III devices do not support partial reconfiguration?

Does anyone has experience of working over Xtremedata XD1000 or XtremeData XD2000i devices which has Stratix II and III respectively as supporting FPGA for a co-processor system?
if yes, then Is partial re-configuration possible through the HyperTransport medium (through AMD processors)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, only 28nm (like Stratix V) and 20nm (Arria 10) devices support Partial Reconfiguration.